# Does anyone know or has anyone developed a simple mechanism for determining the 2d position of elements transformed using CSS 3D transformations

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, transformation, coordinate-systems

I'm writing a 3d library in JavaScript that leverages Webkits 3d transformations (I'd love to post the code publicly, but it's for a client). But the kind of HTML markup it generates looks something like this:

```
<div id="world">
  <span class="pivot" id="map">
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -512px; top: -512px; width: 1024px; height: 1024px;">
      <img src="images/test-grid-1024px.png" />
    </div>
    <span class="pivot" style="-webkit-transform: translate3d(256px,0px,0px) rotateZ(-30deg) rotateX(-90deg);">
      <div class="marker">Marker<br/><span style="font-size: 48px; font-weight: bold;">1</span></div>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Anyway, one of the things that seems to be critically missing from the Webkit 3d CSS stuff is simple mechanisms for converting between coordinate systems, i.e. determining where an object is relative to the page (or some other element) in 2d coordinates. Similarly, it would be great to be able to take a 2d coordinate from the page and project it onto the plane of a transformed element.

This shouldn't be enormously difficult to do but I'd rather not do it if someone else already has. Or if it's been added to Webkit and I simply can't find the docs, that would be awesome.

Comment: __If this isn't obvious__: "div#world" is styled to preserve 3d transformations all the way down. "div.pivot" operates as the container for any 3d transformed element and can be nested per typical scene graphs.